# Trigger animation when svg is in the viewport

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animations

Trigger animation when svg is in the viewport

I have a page with a big header image and an svg animation below the fold.
Here's the example:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.header-image {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffcc00
}

/*Line animations*/
.line {
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  animation: dash 2s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);;
  -webkit-animation: dash 2s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#line01, #line02 {
  animation-delay:1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
}

#line03, #line04 {
  animation-delay:1.2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1.2s;
}
#line05, #line06 {
  animation-delay:1.6s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1.6s;
}
#line07, #line08 {
  animation-delay:1.9s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:1.9s;
}

#line09, #line10 {
  animation-delay:2.3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:2.3s;
}

#line11,
#line12,
#line13,
#line14,
#line15,
#line16,
#line17,
#line18{
  animation-delay:3.1s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:3.1s;
}
#line19,
#line20,
#line21,
#line22,
#line23,
#line24,
#line25,
#line26{
  animation-delay:3.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay:3.5s;
}

/*Keyframes*/
@keyframes dash {
  0% {stroke-dashoffset: 150;}
  100% {stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  0% {stroke-dashoffset: 150;}
  100% {stroke-dashoffset: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="header-image">Please scroll down</div>

<div class="svg-animation">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="guida" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 480.669 305.346" enable-background="new 0 0 480.669 305.346" xml:space="preserve">
    <rect id="ombra-carta01" x="52.2" y="31.8" transform="matrix(-0.9026 0.4305 -0.4305 -0.9026 331.4025 234.5817)" fill="#A2DEF1" width="174" height="246.1"/>
    <path id="ombra-occhiali" fill="#A2DEF1" d="M406.66 105.7 c-4.273-0.759-20.888-8.967-33.1-12.474c-12.225-3.512-30.973-5.673-34.362-5.288c-4.051 0.459-4.223 0.747-4.973 3.6 c-0.75 2.86-0.772 5.4 1.3 6.642c2.683 1.5 2.2 5 1.9 14.967c-2.108 4.115-3.231 8.417-3.774 11.1 c-1.042 5.2 3.5 8.4 6.4 3.745c2.822 4.8 8.4 8.9 19 11.889c18.588 5.2 27.35-5.681 30.177-9.188 c5.041-6.253 5.85-16.103 15.383-14.193c9.534 1.9 6.7 11.2 8.9 18.887c1.259 4.3 4.9 17.9 24.1 20.2 c10.921 1.3 17.632-0.292 22.104-3.697c0.914 5.5 6.3 4.3 7.35-0.96c0.546-2.726 1.171-7.168 0.795-11.811 c3.57-9.194 4.472-12.6 7.528-12.981c2.4-0.299 3.373-2.688 3.782-5.617c0.41-2.93 0.362-3.263-3.2-5.246 c-2.979-1.66-21.113-6.885-33.747-8.354C430.991 105.7 416.7 107.5 406.7 105.694z"/>
    <path id="fine-asta-dx" fill="#254659" d="M333.111 84.4 c23.972 4.3 106.6 28 118.9 33.554c12.3 5.5 10.6 21.7 9.3 28.158c-1.297 6.473-9.299 6.76-7.104-4.195 c2.193-10.955 2.428-17.082-5.075-19.285c-7.504-2.203-109.515-28.483-116.636-30.113C325.357 90.9 328.4 83.2 333.1 84.4 z"/>
    <path id="fine-asta-sx" fill="#254659" d="M469.952 111.8 c-23.768-5.291-109.196-15.194-122.675-14.834c-13.479 0.359-18.091 15.947-19.387 22.421s5.978 9.8 8.172-1.136 c2.194-10.955 4.337-16.699 12.11-15.843c7.773 0.9 112 15.9 119.2 17.127C474.609 120.8 474.8 112.5 470 111.8 z"/>
    <path id="montatura" d="M435.583 151.139c16.586 1.1 22.116-5.72 25.721-14.82 c4.24-10.709 5.044-14.575 8.313-14.983c2.399-0.299 3.372-2.688 3.782-5.617c0.409-2.93 0.362-3.263-3.201-5.246 c-2.979-1.66-21.113-6.885-33.747-8.354c-0.287-0.033-0.577-0.063-0.868-0.093v3.04c10.722 1.3 21.4 4.6 24 7 c5.566 5 0.8 22.641-5.935 30.514c-3.718 4.371-10.928 6.027-18.09 5.686V151.139z M400.826 100.8 c-4.274-0.759-20.888-8.967-33.101-12.475c-1.937-0.556-4.037-1.078-6.215-1.562v3.164c10.889 2.3 22.7 6.8 25.8 13.1 c4.493 9.401-9.373 27.347-19.625 29.896c-1.816 0.452-3.909 0.615-6.135 0.52v2.915c12.997 0.5 19.536-7.608 21.905-10.548 c5.042-6.253 5.85-16.103 15.384-14.193c9.533 1.9 6.7 11.2 8.9 18.887c1.258 4.3 4.9 17.9 24.1 20.2 c1.308 0.2 2.6 0.3 3.7 0.354v-2.87c-6.226-0.296-12.414-2.102-16.24-4.946c-8.479-6.302-14.364-28.202-6.597-35.148 c4.281-3.828 13.587-4.225 22.837-3.108v-3.04C424.432 100.9 410.6 102.6 400.8 100.828z M361.51 86.8 c-11.565-2.569-25.294-4.049-28.147-3.726c-4.051 0.459-4.223 0.747-4.973 3.608c-0.75 2.86-0.772 5.4 1.3 6.6 c2.86 1.6 2.1 5.5 1.9 17.028c-0.191 10.5 2.7 19.4 21.6 24.697c3.01 0.8 5.8 1.3 8.3 1.36v-2.915 c-9.958-0.431-22.591-6.071-25.262-14.423c-3.147-9.843-0.785-27.983 6.275-30.445c2.736-0.953 10.573-0.455 19 1.337V86.792z"/>
    <path id="riflesso-bottom" fill="#B0CAD9" d="M342.523 88.6 c6.276-2.188 39.4 3.3 44.7 14.452c4.493 9.401-9.373 27.347-19.625 29.896c-9.948 2.477-28.129-3.686-31.396-13.903 C333.102 109.2 335.5 91.1 342.5 88.619L342.523 88.619z M459.608 112.069c-4.949-4.436-37.619-12.161-46.861-3.896 c-7.768 6.946-1.882 28.8 6.6 35.148c8.228 6.1 27.4 7.4 34.33-0.739C460.369 134.7 465.2 117.1 459.6 112.069z"/>
    <path id="riflesso-top-sx" fill="#D1E2EB" d="M345.894 88.2 c10.529-0.32 36.7 5.1 41.4 14.913c3.151 6.594-2.729 17.39-10.059 24.13L345.894 88.158z"/>
    <path id="riflesso-top-dx" fill="#D1E2EB" d="M418.783 105.355l31.898 39.8 c1.146-0.716 2.158-1.559 2.992-2.539c6.695-7.873 11.501-25.523 5.935-30.514C455.452 108.3 431.7 102.3 418.8 105.355z"/>
    <path id="retro-aste" fill="#617F91" d="M452.192 108.6 c-8.324-1.297-18.175-2.673-28.473-4.008c-2.935 0.211-5.595 0.716-7.759 1.6l0 0l-0.059 0.024l-0.017 0.007l-0.041 0 l-0.059 0.024l-0.058 0.025h-0.001l-0.057 0.024l-0.058 0.024l-0.042 0.019l-0.016 0.007l-0.113 0.051l-0.026 0.013l-0.029 0 l-0.057 0.026l-0.056 0.026l-0.011 0.004l-0.045 0.022l-0.056 0.026l-0.051 0.024l-0.004 0.002l-0.055 0.026l-0.055 0 l-0.035 0.018l-0.02 0.011l-0.054 0.026l-0.054 0.028l-0.021 0.01l-0.033 0.019l-0.054 0.028l-0.013 0.007l-0.087 0 l-0.005 0.003l-0.053 0.029l-0.043 0.023l-0.009 0.006l-0.053 0.028l-0.052 0.029l-0.027 0.016l-0.023 0.014l-0.051 0 l-0.051 0.029l-0.051 0.03l-0.05 0.03l-0.051 0.03l0 0l-0.05 0.03l-0.05 0.031l-0.049 0.031l-0.049 0.031l-0.048 0.031l-0.022 0 l-0.026 0.018l-0.048 0.031l-0.048 0.032l-0.009 0.006l-0.039 0.026l-0.08 0.056l-0.009 0.006l-0.005 0.004l-0.009 0 l-0.084 0.06l-0.029 0.021l-0.017 0.012l-0.046 0.034l-0.046 0.033l-0.016 0.013l-0.029 0.021l-0.045 0.034l-0.044 0 l-0.005 0.003l-0.039 0.031l-0.045 0.035l-0.035 0.028l-0.008 0.006l-0.003 0.002l-0.084 0.069l-0.023 0.02l-0.019 0 l-0.085 0.071l-0.011 0.011l-0.113 0.099l-0.043 0.039l-0.014 0.013l-0.029 0.026l-0.026 0.024l-0.017 0.015l-0.039 0 l-0.002 0.002l-0.042 0.04l-0.012 0.011l-0.03 0.03l-0.024 0.023l-0.017 0.017l-0.037 0.037l-0.004 0.004l-0.041 0.041l-0.009 0 l-0.031 0.032l-0.021 0.021l-0.019 0.021l-0.034 0.035l-0.005 0.007l-0.04 0.042c-0.938 1.008-1.644 2.262-2.142 3.7 c19.726 5.1 36.2 9.4 39 10.253c7.503 2.2 7.3 8.3 5.1 19.285l-0.005 0.024c2.821-3.578 5.257-8.839 6.642-14.028 c-1.398-4.124-4.051-7.831-8.789-9.959c-0.717-0.322-1.673-0.705-2.843-1.144c5.22 0.8 9.6 1.4 12.8 1.9 c-0.122-2.879-0.866-5.261-2.421-6.654C458.445 111 455.8 109.8 452.2 108.647L452.192 108.647z M350.696 88.3 c8.174 2 17.8 4.5 27.8 7.258c2.633 1.3 4.9 2.8 6.6 4.476h0.001l0.044 0.045l0.006 0 c0.072 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.2 0.219l0.025 0.027l0.018 0.019l0.042 0.045l0.043 0.045l0.014 0.015l0.028 0.031l0.041 0 l0.042 0.046l0.002 0.002l0.039 0.043l0.04 0.046l0.032 0.036l0.009 0.01l0.04 0.046l0.04 0.046l0.021 0.024l0.019 0 l0.039 0.046l0.039 0.047l0.011 0.012l0.028 0.034l0.038 0.047l0.038 0.046l0 0l0.037 0.047l0.038 0.047l0.026 0.033l0.01 0 l0.037 0.047l0.035 0.047l0.037 0.047l0.035 0.047l0.036 0.047l0.006 0.01l0.028 0.038l0.034 0.047l0.033 0.044l0.002 0 l0.034 0.048l0.033 0.048l0.022 0.031l0.011 0.016l0.033 0.048l0.032 0.048l0.013 0.019l0.021 0.029l0.031 0.047l0.032 0 l0.004 0.006l0.027 0.042l0.03 0.048l0.026 0.041l0.005 0.007l0.03 0.049l0.029 0.048l0.019 0.028l0.012 0.021l0.029 0 l0.029 0.049l0.009 0.017l0.019 0.032l0.028 0.048l0.028 0.049l0.002 0.004l0.025 0.046l0.026 0.049l0.022 0.039l0.005 0 l0.026 0.05l0.04 0.075l0.013 0.022l0.05 0.099l0.007 0.014l0.018 0.036l0.048 0.099l0.024 0.053l0.009 0.017l0.016 0 l0.016 0.033l0.009 0.019l0.022 0.051l0.001 0.002l0.023 0.053l0.007 0.015l0.016 0.039l0.014 0.031l0.009 0.021l0.021 0 l0.001 0.005l0.022 0.053l0.005 0.013l0.017 0.041l0.041 0.108l0.021 0.054l0.004 0.011l0.016 0 c0.462 1.3 0.6 2.7 0.5 4.182c-20.156-2.878-36.996-5.244-39.944-5.569c-7.773-0.856-9.917 4.888-12.11 15.843l-0.021 0.1 c-1.242-4.382-1.474-10.187-0.757-15.526c2.882-3.294 6.772-5.718 11.993-5.857c0.785-0.021 1.816-0.007 3.1 0 c-5.132-1.308-9.462-2.407-12.614-3.198c1.222-2.61 2.826-4.521 4.797-5.208C343.999 88.1 347 88 350.7 88.319z"/>
    <path id="riflesso-aste-top-sx" fill="#8097A6" d="M345.893 88.158l12.551 15.6 c7.396 1 18 2.5 29.7 4.194c0.09-1.494-0.073-2.904-0.535-4.182l-0.016-0.044l-0.004-0.011l-0.021-0.054l-0.041-0.108 l-0.017-0.041l-0.005-0.013l-0.022-0.053l-0.001-0.005l-0.021-0.049l-0.009-0.021l-0.014-0.031l-0.016-0.039l-0.007-0.015 l-0.023-0.053l-0.001-0.002l-0.022-0.051l-0.009-0.019l-0.016-0.033l-0.016-0.036l-0.009-0.017l-0.024-0.053l-0.048-0.099 l-0.018-0.036l-0.007-0.014l-0.05-0.099l-0.013-0.022l-0.04-0.075l-0.026-0.05l-0.005-0.009l-0.022-0.039l-0.026-0.049l-0.025-0.046 l-0.002-0.004l-0.028-0.049l-0.028-0.048l-0.019-0.032l-0.009-0.017l-0.029-0.049l-0.029-0.048l-0.012-0.021l-0.019-0.028 l-0.029-0.048l-0.03-0.049l-0.005-0.007l-0.026-0.041l-0.03-0.048l-0.027-0.042l-0.004-0.006l-0.032-0.049l-0.031-0.047 l-0.021-0.029l-0.013-0.019l-0.032-0.048l-0.033-0.048l-0.011-0.016l-0.022-0.031l-0.033-0.048l-0.034-0.048l-0.002-0.003 l-0.033-0.044l-0.034-0.047l-0.028-0.038l-0.006-0.01l-0.036-0.047l-0.035-0.047l-0.037-0.047l-0.035-0.047l-0.037-0.047 l-0.01-0.013l-0.026-0.033l-0.038-0.047l-0.037-0.047l0 0l-0.038-0.046l-0.038-0.047l-0.028-0.034l-0.011-0.012l-0.039-0.047 l-0.039-0.046l-0.019-0.021l-0.021-0.024l-0.04-0.046l-0.04-0.046l-0.009-0.01l-0.032-0.036l-0.04-0.046l-0.039-0.043l-0.002-0.002 l-0.042-0.046l-0.041-0.046l-0.028-0.031l-0.014-0.015l-0.043-0.045l-0.042-0.045l-0.018-0.019l-0.025-0.027 c-0.07-0.073-0.142-0.146-0.214-0.219l-0.006-0.006l-0.044-0.045h-0.001c-1.659-1.653-3.926-3.147-6.559-4.476 c-10.013-2.731-19.623-5.251-27.797-7.258C348.887 88.2 347.3 88.1 345.9 88.158z"/>
    <path id="riflesso-aste-top-dx" fill="#8097A6" d="M452.192 108.6 c-8.324-1.297-18.175-2.673-28.473-4.008c-1.761 0.126-3.422 0.358-4.937 0.716l9.427 11.751c10.996 2.9 19 5 20.9 5.5 c7.503 2.2 7.3 8.3 5.1 19.285l-0.005 0.024c2.821-3.578 5.257-8.839 6.642-14.028c-1.398-4.124-4.051-7.831-8.789-9.959 c-0.717-0.322-1.673-0.705-2.843-1.144c5.22 0.8 9.6 1.4 12.8 1.898c-0.122-2.879-0.866-5.261-2.421-6.654 C458.445 111 455.8 109.8 452.2 108.647z"/>
    <rect id="carta01" x="46.3" y="26.9" transform="matrix(-0.9026 0.4305 -0.4305 -0.9026 318.206 227.8356)" fill="#FFFFFF" width="174" height="246.1"/>
    <line class="line" id="line26" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="182.6" y1="239.7" x2="224" y2="220"/>
    <line class="line" id="line25" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="179.3" y1="232.8" x2="238.6" y2="204.6"/>
    <line class="line" id="line24" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="176.1" y1="226" x2="235.3" y2="197.7"/>
    <line class="line" id="line23" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="172.8" y1="219.1" x2="232.1" y2="190.9"/>
    <line class="line" id="line22" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="169.5" y1="212.2" x2="228.8" y2="184"/>
    <line class="line" id="line21" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="166.2" y1="205.4" x2="225.6" y2="177.2"/>
    <line class="line" id="line20" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="163" y1="198.5" x2="222.3" y2="170.3"/>
    <line class="line" id="line19" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="159.7" y1="191.7" x2="219" y2="163.4"/>
    <line class="line" id="line18" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="113.7" y1="272.5" x2="142.6" y2="258.7"/>
    <line class="line" id="line17" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="110.4" y1="265.6" x2="168.8" y2="237.8"/>
    <line class="line" id="line16" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="107.1" y1="258.8" x2="165.5" y2="231"/>
    <line class="line" id="line15" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="103.9" y1="251.9" x2="162.3" y2="224.1"/>
    <line class="line" id="line14" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="100.6" y1="245" x2="159" y2="217.3"/>
    <line class="line" id="line13" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="97.3" y1="238.2" x2="155.7" y2="210.4"/>
    <line class="line" id="line12" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="94.1" y1="231.3" x2="152.4" y2="203.5"/>
    <line class="line" id="line11" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="90.8" y1="224.5" x2="149.2" y2="196.7"/>
    <line class="line" id="line10" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="62.5" y1="166.6" x2="118.3" y2="140.1"/>
    <line class="line" id="line09" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="59.3" y1="159.7" x2="187.5" y2="98.7"/>
    <line class="line" id="line08" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="56" y1="152.9" x2="184.2" y2="91.8"/>
    <line class="line" id="line07" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="52.7" y1="146" x2="181" y2="85"/>
    <line class="line" id="line06" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="49.5" y1="139.1" x2="177.7" y2="78.1"/>
    <line class="line" id="line05" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="46.2" y1="132.3" x2="174.4" y2="71.3"/>
    <line class="line" id="line04" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="42.9" y1="125.4" x2="171.2" y2="64.4"/>
    <line class="line" id="line03" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="39.7" y1="118.6" x2="167.9" y2="57.5"/>
    <line class="line" id="line02" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="36.4" y1="111.7" x2="164.6" y2="50.7"/>
    <line class="line" id="line01" fill="none" stroke="#CCCCCC" stroke-width="4.5" x1="54.4" y1="82.6" x2="130.7" y2="46.3"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qx7p46f3/4/

By the time the user has scrolled down, the animation has already played because it starts as soon as the page is loaded. I want to trigger it when the `svg` is in the viewport instead, when the user scrolls to that specific part of the page. How can I do that?

I don't know much about js but I'd rather not use jquery cause it doesn't seem to be the most efficient solution in this case, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know much about javascript, then you might want to consider jQuery since it will be a lot easier for you to accomplish the desired effect.

Using a plugin like [jQuery.onScreen](http://silvestreh.github.io/onScreen/) you could simply write:

```
$('svg').onScreen({
  container: window,
  direction: 'vertical',
  toggleClass: 'onScreen',
});
```

And in your css:

```
.onScreen .line {
  animation: dash 2s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);;
  -webkit-animation: dash 2s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

**Edit:**
Without jQuery:

```
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.svg-animation');

window.onscroll = function (event) {
  if (wrapper.getBoundingClientRect().top < 0) {
    wrapper.className = "svg-animation onScreen";
    window.onscroll = null;
  }
}
```

Please note that this hasn't been tested in all browsers and I can't guarantee full support.
Here's a working demo: http://codepen.io/btpoe/pen/caeb32b678521d82144ae1f953c3e332

Comment: Thanks. I would be using for this specific case only so it seemed a bit overkill, load jquery, then a plugin just for one animation. I was hoping it would be easier with vanilla JS but I couldn't find a tutorial anywhere.

Comment: Did you see my edit? I added a vanilla JS alternative for you.