# reveal svg animation when entering viewport

Tags: jquery, css, animation, svg, viewport

I'm having a problem. I played around with svg animation inside the `.svg`-file. this works fine and if I add this in a `<object>` it shows the animation I did with css. all fine.
But this svg isn't on top of the page so if the user scrolls there, the animation is already done. Sure, I could add a infinite-argument to it, but this would look to crazy. So it's my question how I can trigger the animation when the svg reaches the viewport.
 Is there any plugin I've not found yet where you can just add a class to every `svg`-object or something like that? Or any other ideas how to achieve that? It should support multiple `svg`-objets on the same page for my needs. I couldn't find any way to do this with `wow.js` or `waypoints.js`. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger animation when svg is in the viewport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341422/trigger-animation-when-svg-is-in-the-viewport)

Comment: That link is for CSS animation, whereas I suspect the OP is using SMIL animation.  Is that correct @eckstein?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau oops, no, I'm not using SMIL, but thank you for this code example. Will have a look into this technique. But for this project I'm animating my svg via CSS. I'm sorry if this caused confusion.

Comment: @MoshFeu Thanks for the link. I'll see if I can use this in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You say that you are using "svg animation", which I am taking to mean you are using SMIL animation (`<animate>` etc) rather than CSS animation.

If that is the case, then what you need to do is set your `begin` attribute to "indefinite" and then call `beginElement()` on the `<animate>` element when you want the animation to begin.

Your code will look something like the following:

```
if (viewPortIsOnScreen())
{
   myObject.contentDocument.getElementById("my_animation").beginElement();
}
```

You can read more about `beginElement()` here:

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#InterfaceElementTimeControl